# How to route linode object bucket to domain name?

Tags: dns, routing, web-hosting, amazon-s3, linode

I have a linode object bucket up and running with my files/folders. I have purchased the domain and have set a CNAME to point to [subdomain].[domain].com.website-us-southeast-1.linodeobjects.com. When I try to access the site through the domain I have to include the /index.html or the page pulls up the bucket in xml, not the site. If I go to [domain].com/index.html everything loads fine but I would like it to route to the /index.html page when a user types in either [subdomain].[domain].com or [domain].com

I used s3cmd to upload the files to linode and here is the following ws-info 
[image: Screenshot of s3cmd output]

and here is the folder structure in the bucket

[image: Folder structure in Linode Bucket]